# Copying the value within a Rc<RefCell<SomeStruct>>

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and have a function that receives a `Rc<RefCell<SomeStruct>>` as a parameter and I want to copy the contents so I no longer have a reference and just have a copy of the `SomeStruct`. Here's what I have: (That doesn't compile)

```
impl GameTree {
    pub fn new(rc_status: Rc<RefCell<SomeStruct>>) -> GameTree {
        let status: SomeStruct = *rc_status.borrow_mut(); // Here is where I'm trying to copy the SomeStruct
        let root = Node::new(status);
        GameTree { root }
    }
}
```

How would I clone the `SomeStruct`?

Comment: Does `SomeStruct` implement either of the traits `Copy` or `Clone`? If so, which one(s)? If not, then you're going to have a very hard time making a copy of it.

Comment: Is this _really_ what you want / need to do? Does `Node::new` need to take ownership of the `status` being passed in? If the status is _generally_ passed around as a reference-counted ref cell, maybe `Node::new` should _also_ take in such a refcell.

Comment: If `SomeStruct` implements `Copy`, this should work. If it impls `Clone`, call `.clone()`. Either way use a `.borrow()`, and consider using `Cell`.

Comment: You should add a definition for `SomeStruct` in your code example. it would be easier to help you. The right answer depends on what `SomeStruct` is.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I clone the SomeStruct?

I'm assuming that SomeStruct implements Clone.

By manually [`deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)ing the [`Ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Ref.html) you get from calling `RefCell::borrow`, you get a `&SomeStruct` that can be directly cloned, otherwise you'll end up cloning the `Ref`, which's not what you want.

Using the `*` operator:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct SomeStruct;

fn get_some_struct_clone(rc_some_struct: Rc<RefCell<SomeStruct>>) -> SomeStruct {
    let some_struct = (*rc_some_struct.borrow()).clone();
    some_struct
}

fn main() {
    let rc_some_struct = Rc::new(RefCell::new(SomeStruct));
    let some_struct_clone = get_some_struct_clone(rc_some_struct.clone());
    println!("{:?}", rc_some_struct);
    println!("{:?}", some_struct_clone);
}
```

Output:

```
RefCell { value: SomeStruct }
SomeStruct
```

That said, as others have commented, maybe it would be best to save the `Rc` itself on your node, or maybe Rc isn't needed at all.